# Rails 4 + ActiveRecord + postgresql + group by do not work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, group-by

I want to make the following query by **ActiveRecord** but I cant't.

```sql
SELECT
  catalog_product_id,
  COUNT (catalog_product_id)
FROM
  sc_items
WHERE sc_items.shopping_cart_id = 34
GROUP BY
  catalog_product_id;
BEGIN

Table: 
scItems(catalog_product_id, shopping_cart_id)
[1,1]
[2,1]
[2,1]
[2,1]
```

I'm doing the following code ruby code:

```ruby
sc_items.select("catalog_product_id, count(catalog_product_id) as count").group("catalog_product_id")
```

That generate this sql:

```sql
SELECT catalog_product_id, count(catalog_product_id) as count FROM "sc_items" WHERE "sc_items"."shopping_cart_id" = $1 GROUP BY catalog_product_id  [["shopping_cart_id", 34]]
```

And I get this result:

```
#<ActiveRecord::AssociationRelation [#<ScItem id: nil, catalog_product_id: 1>, #<ScItem id: nil, catalog_product_id: 3>]>
```

By other hand if I execute the above sql:

```ruby
res = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)
res.class
res.to_a
```

I get this:

```
#<PG::Result:0x007fcb3720bea8 status=PGRES_TUPLES_OK ntuples=2 nfields=2 cmd_tuples=2> 
PG::Result 
[{"catalog_product_id"=>"2", "count"=>"3"}, {"catalog_product_id"=>"1", "count"=>"1"}]
```

This is the correct result, How can I make this query using ActiveRecord?. And why the activeRecord lacks the id of catalog_product_id if the sql is the same?

Additional information:

- 'rails', '4.2.0'
- 'pg', '~> 0.18.1'
- ruby '2.1.2'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you have a model named ScItem

```
ScItem.where(shopping_cart_id: 34).group(:catalog_product_id).count
```

You can find more details about group by and count [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#total-of-grouped-items)

Answer (score 0):

To Group entire table by some attribute i have used

```
ScItem.unscoped.group(:catalog_product_id).count
```